# How do I make an object go towards another object?

Tags: game-engine

I know this seems like it has a really simple solution: do a tracking sensor. But for some odd reason, whenever I do this, the moving object just sort of spasms around like a fish. I tried all of the tracking axis, and they all just have different ways of freaking out. It just doesn't make sense to me! Basically I am trying to achieve a sonic homing attack sort of move, and so far it only works a bit, because it knows exactly which enemy to pick and to put a circle around, but then when you try to perform the actual attack it just does the fish spasm thing. It just seems like it doesn't know what it is doing...

Comment: We need more detail about your set up.

Comment: Typically the tracking looks like random turns when the object is very close to the target. In other words, it steps from in-front of the towards the target, but the step ends behind the target, facing away. This makes the track-to turn the object.The forward motion should end when the distance to the target is less then the next step. (The next step can be placed directly on the target position = partial step, without tracking).

Comment: I know what you mean but it isn't that, because the target can be in any position and nothing changes.

Comment: So your tracking object is not near the target object?

Comment: Okay so I figured out what the problem was and it is a lot more complex than I thought. It isn't the tracking that is wrong, it is what it wants to track TO. Basically the item gets added in for tracking, but the one in the second layer is the one being tracked to... so it just tries to track to a seemingly non-existent tracking point. I want it to track to "Track.001" but that doesn't exist yet so what do I do?